# Recovering ext4 directories using ext4magic

Tags: linux, ubuntu, data-recovery, ext4

I just deleted everything from my user's home directory (/XXX/ * instead of /XXX/* !) and I found ext4magic tool to recover that data. I'm currently on Ubuntu booted from USB drive, so the partition I'm trying to recover is unmounted.

I did try to use ext4magic already and it did pretty well, but I think I'm missing some options / configs to make it work the way I'd like.

I recovered XYZ/ directory and it should contain .git subdirectory in it, but when I run the ext4magic for my "root" (as in main) user's directory the .git subdirectory was not recovered. I did run it once again for that specific directory (XYZ/.git) and it was recovered. So I suppose I missed something, because the .git subdirectory seems fine, therefore it is recoverable. I suppose there are plenty of subdirectories not recovered by my initial ext4magic run. Is there any switch / option to look "deeper" into directories structure? Or do I need to run it for each directory the initial run missed?

Forgive me if any of the above seems unclear, but I'm pretty much "in hurry" to recover that stuff and can't really focus on explaining the scenario!

## EDIT

This is the command I used
`sudo ext4magic /dev/sda6 -r -f /add -d /media/ubuntu/backup/rec/add`

Comment: What options did you use? From the manpage I think you need -m and -R, but maybe take a look yourself? http://ext4magic.sourceforge.net/manpage_en.html

Comment: I just edited my question with command. Would -m flag change anything there? :) Also I can't combine -m and -R in one go, should I use -R first and then -m the second time?

Comment: Also when I use -m flag, the -f flag is ignored. Is that expected behavior? I also wanted to ask, any other tools recommended? Unfortunately the way I run it didn't recover certain files that I must recover. The rest is not that important, because they have a backup, but few of them I can't afford to lose (and please, don't tell me how stupid that was, I know!)